# Load lower quality image if higher one inst available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a folder of images that look like this

```
- img
-- 001
--- banner_620x350.jpg
--- banner_300x130.jpg
--- banner_180x60.jpg
-- 002
--- banner_300x130.jpg
--- banner_180x60.jpg
-- 003
--- banner_180x60.jpg
```

My current way to load an image looks like this

```
<img src="img/003/banner_620x350.jpg" alt="001" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='img/003/banner_180x60.jpg';" />
```

because we well always have a 180x60 image but we not always have a 600x350 or 300x130

What I would like to do is this

```
if 600x350 exists uses it
else if does 300x130 exists use it
else use 180x60
```

PS: I can't check server side.

Comment: why not managing server side?

Comment: I can user server side on the server the website is on. has to JavaScript or jquery

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to figure this out myself and want to make a quick edit, I meant to say `can't`

Comment: Perhaps this thread is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019077/detecting-a-image-404-in-javascript. I think that a server side solution will be more efficient, e.g. keep in db which image exists and use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function that checks if the image can be loaded, if it can't, move on to the next etc. and if all of them fails, it still returns the last one in the array :

```
function checkSource(src) {
    var def = $.Deferred(),
        res = ['620x350', '180x60', '180x60'];

    (function s(i) {
        $('<img />', {src : (src + '_' + res[i] + '.jpg')}).on({
            load: function() {
                def.resolve(this.src);
            },
            error: function() {
                if (i != res.length-1) {
                    s(++i);
                }else{
                    def.resolve(this.src);
                }
            }
        });
    }(0));
    return def.promise();
};
```

You can call it like :

```
checkSource('banner').done(function(file) {
    $('img#banner').prop('src', file);
});
```

and it sets the source to whatever image could be loaded, in the order of the `res` array, i.e. in this order :

banner_620x350.jpg
banner_300x130.jpg
banner_180x60.jpg

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mWDfL/1/)

Comment: Works exactly as I would expect! And looks beautiful!